# How to force 16.04 servers to close the connection?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, tmux

Since I upgraded some of my servers from 14.04 to 16.04, I encounter one problem.

Suddenly SSH sessions initiated *to* those 16.04 servers from within a running Tmux session will no longer disconnect if I issue a `sudo reboot` or (as root) `reboot` on those remote servers.

Instead I will see the wall message about the system going down for reboot and then ... nothing. Occasionally I have encountered some timeouts, but only after a long - unacceptably long - waiting period.

The only way to recover a Tmux pane in which I ran one of these SSH sessions is by killing it (<kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> and then `respawn-pane -k`).

Since this also happens *from* old 14.04 machines with the older Tmux and SSH client versions, I suspect that the problem is purely on the server-side.

How can I configure 16.04 to cause a forced disconnect to clients connected via some TCP-based protocol upon rebooting?

The same still happens with 18.04, upgraded or freshly installed. No matter.